# C# HttpClient 303 SeeOther bug

Tags: c#, httpclient

HttpClient automatically handles 303 (SeeOther) as described in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpstatuscode(v=vs.118).aspx

> SeeOther automatically redirects the client to the URI specified in
>   the Location header as the result of a POST. The request to the
>   resource specified by the Location header will be made with a GET.

The same behavior seems to happen on GET requests, but the call fails as if my Authorization header was missing.

I set the header using

```
public void SetOauthToken(String key, String token)
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(key, token);
    }
```

I am able to fix the error by intercepting the 303 and calling the URI from Location header by hand.

For example I change

```
public async Task<T> GetXML<T>(String url)
    {
        using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url))
        {

            string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

            return (T)serializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(result));

        }
    }
```

to

```
public async Task<T> GetXML<T>(String url)
    {
        using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url))
        {
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.SeeOther)
            {
                return await GetXML<T>(response.Headers.Location.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

                return (T)serializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(result));
            }
        }
    }
```

and it fixes the bug.

When examining the redirect request everything seems fine. The redirect call works from Postman.

Any idea why is this happening?

Answer (score -2):

First, don't always believe the http status responses.  Websites often change the values to make it harder for hackers to get access to the server.  When a Http connection is made a negotiation takes place between client and server using the http headers.  The negotiation attempts to get a common mode for the transfer.  For example a server may be designed to work in English, French, and German.  The client includes English in the header so the client will then connect to the English webpages.   So you leaving out the AuthenticationHeaderValue is not a bug, but a line of code that is required.  A IE webpage is more robust than the Net Http Client and sends more default headers.  If you used a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and compared the headers using an IE and you application you would see the differences.

Comment: I agree with what you are saying, but your response has little to do with my question.

Comment: You fixed the issue by changing http headers, right?  So isn't that what I said?

Comment: No, I solved it by disabling auto handle of 303. Headers are the same.

Comment: Disabling the auto handle of 303 effectively changes the http headers since the Net client doesn't respond to the server with the wrong headers.